# why get(key, value) returns the correct value even if you type in the wrong value into the value spot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, get

so I know what this method does, but i am trying to understand why it does this. For example:

`dic = {'a':500, 'b':600}`

`dic.get('a', 5)`

`#output`

`500`

i would expect this to be invalid. but it seems to just print the correct value instead of the incorrect value i typed. why does this do that, or is there something else happening that i am missing. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect it to be invalid? 'a' is an existing key in `dic`

Comment: The second (optional) argument to get() is a default value - i.e., if the key 'a' is not present then it will return the default. The behaviour in this case is as expected. Try *dic.get('c', 5)* and see what happens

Comment: _so I know what this method does_, no, actually it is obvious you don't know what it does, especially the second, optional argument.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I feel this may answer. I am just not sure about why is would be valid if my value is off by 495. edit. Someone below answered. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Please, read again [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):  get(key[, default]) Return the value for _key_ **if key is in the dictionary, else** _default_.

Comment: @guywhoasksquestions I think you're misunderstanding the answers. `dict.get()` tries to get a value from the key you give it, and if it doesn't find it it returns `None` by default. However, if you give it a _second_ parameter, 5 in your case, it will return that if it doesn't find the key. Try outputting `dic.get('c', 5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the docs for dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) you will see that the second argument is meant to be returned if there is no key present in the dictionary.

For example:

```
my_dict = {"a": 100, "b": 200}
print(my_dict.get("a", 200))  # 100
print(my_dict.get("c", 300))  # 300
print(my_dict["c"])           # raised KeyError
```

Comment: @guywhoasksquestions glad that is clarified. Accept the answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.get()` takes a key and optional value parameter, which is returned if the key is not found and does not compare it to the value of the key. I don't know why you *would* want to use it like that, but you could use this to get your result:

```py
dic = {'a': 500, 'b': 600}

key, value = 'a', 5
result = dic.get(key)

if result is None or result != value:
    print("Key value pair not found.")
```

Comment: It does not work if we have a value of `None` in the dictionary. If we really want to check if a pair `key -> value` exists in a dictionary, we would better use `d[key]` with handling the `KeyError` exception.

Comment: That may be true, but I'm going to make an assumption and say that OP will _not_ have `None` keys in his dictionary, and putting in a safeguard for that case would unnecessarily complicate the code.